# Ignoring subtrees with a certain tag

Tags: org-babel

I want to ignore a subtree temporarily.
I can do this by setting the property `:header-args:` to `:tangle
no`, but this is not usually visible.  Could I have this property
set automatically by all subtrees tagged with `:notangle:`, and
removed when the tag is removed; or something to a similar effect?

Comment: If the subtree will be commented (e.g. with `C-c ;`) it will not be tangled.

Comment: @KonstantinMorenko, perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could comment the subtree with `C-c ;` (`org-toggle-comment`).  If the subtree marked `COMMENT`, it will not be tangled.  I use it into my init files (with `org-babel-load-file`) to temporary exclude some code.

Comment: If you require you can modify the actual word that triggers the `:notangle:` behavior moreover you can put there a regex (setq org-comment-string "\\(EXCL:\\|COMM:\\|NOTE:\\|PLOT:\\|CTRL:\\)") (set-face-attribute 'org-special-keyword nil :foreground "#ff66cc" :background 'unspecified :weight 'bold)